# Converting lists of tuples to strings Python

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I've written a function in python that returns a list, for example

```
[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
```

But i want the output as a string so i can replace the comma with another char so the output would be

```
'1@1' '2@2' '3@3'
```

Any easy way around this?:)
Thanks for any tips in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This looks like a `list` of `tuple`s, where each `tuple` has two elements.

```
' '.join(['%d@%d' % (t[0],t[1]) for t in l])
```

Which can of course be simplified to:

```
' '.join(['%d@%d' % t for t in l])
```

Or even:

```
' '.join(map(lambda t: '%d@%d' % t, l))
```

Where `l` is your original `list`. This generates 'number@number' pairs for each tuple in the list. These pairs are then joined with spaces (`' '`).

The `join` syntax looked a little weird to me when I first started woking with Python, but [the documentation](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/string.html#string.join) was a huge help.

Comment: instead of (' ') could i add \n somewhere so the output returns as a column with one string on each new line?

Comment: Sure you can! Why not try `print '\n'.join('%d@%d' % t for t in l)` in the Python interpreter?

Answer (score 4):

You could convert the tuples to strings by using the % operator with a list comprehension or generator expression, e.g.

```
ll = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
['%d@%d' % aa for aa in ll]
```

This would return a list of strings like:

```
['1@1', '2@2', '3@3']
```

You can concatenate the resulting list of strings together for output.  [This article](http://skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) describes half a dozen different approaches with benchmarks and analysis of their relative merits.

Answer (score 3):

`' '.join([str(a)+"@"+str(b) for (a,b) in [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]])`

or for arbitrary tuples in the list,

`' '.join(['@'.join([str(v) for v in k]) for k in [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]])`

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: ' '.join('%d@%d' % (el[0], el[1]) for el in [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)])
Out[1]: '1@1 2@2 3@3'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[ str(e[0]) + ',' + str(e[1]) for e in [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)] ]
```

This is if you want them in a collection of string, I didn't understand it if you want a single output string or a collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
[str(item).replace(',','@') for item in [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need `join` and `str` in a generator comprehension.

```
>>> ['@'.join(str(i) for i in t) for t in l]
['1@1', '2@2', '3@3']

>>> ' '.join('@'.join(str(i) for i in t) for t in l)
'1@1 2@2 3@3'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) function and then just replace bits of the string:

```
>>> original = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
>>> intermediate = repr(original)
>>> print intermediate
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
>>> final = intermediate.replace('), (', ' ').replace('[(','').replace(')]','').replace(', ','@')
>>> print final
1@1 2@2 3@3
```

but this will only work if you know for certain that none of tuples have the following character sequences which need to be preserved in the final result: `), (`, `[(`, `)]`, `,`